# Prove that the Gaussian integers Z [i] form an integral domain

Tags: ring-theory, integral-domain, gaussian-integers

This is all I have done. Is this correct? please explain.

Proof.
0 = 0 + 0i is in Z [i] :
Also note that 1 = 1 + 0i is in z[i].

Then (a + bi)(c + di) = (ac) + (bd)i is in Z [i] and (a + bi)(c + di) = (ac-bd) + (ad + bc)i is in
Z [i].
Therefore Z [i] is a subring of C.

Hence Z [i] is a commutative ring with unity. Furthermore, if
(a + bi) (c + di) = 0; then (as elements of the integral domain C) either a + bi = 0 or c + di = 0.
Therefore Z [i] is an integral domain.

Comment: It's crucial to know what is your definition of the Gaussian integers., and also do you know basic results about quotient rings? Please add that to your question. This will almost surely end up being a dupe, but we need to know more to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that the Gaussian Integers are an integral domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716472/prove-that-the-gaussian-integers-are-an-integral-domain)

Answer (score 1):

Your explaination of $\mathbb Z[i]$ being a subring of $\mathbb C$ is confusing. Are you using $xy$ to both denote the additive and multiplication operations on $x$ and $y$ in the ring structure?

You don't need to show that $0+0i\in\mathbb Z[i]$. To show that $(\mathbb Z[i],+,\times)$ is a subring of $(\mathbb C, +,\times)$, you only need to show the following (called the Subring Test):

1. $\mathbb Z[i]\neq\emptyset$
2. $x+(-y)\in\mathbb Z[i]$ for all $x, y\in\mathbb Z[i]$
3. $xy\in\mathbb Z[i]$ for all $x, y\in\mathbb Z[i]$

Showing this:

1. Non-emptyness is clear.
2. $(a+bi)-(c+di)=(a-c)+(b-d)i\in\mathbb Z[i]$
3. You showed this.

No need to point out commutivity. Your explanation of why it is a domain is good. In fact, this same argument is used to show that every subring with unity of an integral domain is an integral domain.